# Moodle: SQL for listing all users (with custom user profile fields)

Tags: sql, database, moodle

I was looking for the proper SQL query to retrieve details of all users with the role `student`. The information would include data of some custom user profile fields.

For example, I have created 2 user profile fields, with the short names `Department` and `PositionRank`. I have managed to retrieve the list with the SQL below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id AS userid, department_data.data AS department, rank_data.data AS rank    
FROM mdl_user u
JOIN mdl_role_assignments ra ON ra.userid = u.id
JOIN mdl_role r ON r.id = ra.roleid AND r.shortname =  'student'    
JOIN mdl_user_info_data department_data ON department_data.userid = u.id
JOIN mdl_user_info_field department_field ON department_data.fieldid = department_field.id AND department_field.shortname = 'Department'    
JOIN mdl_user_info_data rank_data ON rank_data.userid = u.id
JOIN mdl_user_info_field rank_field ON rank_data.fieldid = rank_field.id AND rank_field.shortname = 'PositionRank'
```

But I feel like there should be a better way. Could anyone please advise?
Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with moodle, but from your query, it looks like an EAV type database. EAV databases' fundamental flaw is the complexity of querying.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a GROUP BY and CASE..ELSE in the columns, so you only have one join to the data table

```
SELECT u.id AS userid,
        MAX(CASE WHEN f.shortname = 'Department' THEN d.data ELSE '' END) AS department,
        MAX(CASE WHEN f.shortname = 'PositionRank' THEN d.data ELSE '' END) AS rank
FROM mdl_user u
JOIN mdl_role_assignments ra ON ra.userid = u.id
JOIN mdl_role r ON r.id = ra.roleid AND r.shortname =  'student'
JOIN mdl_user_info_data d ON d.userid = u.id
JOIN mdl_user_info_field f ON d.fieldid = f.id
WHERE f.shortname IN ('Department', 'PositionRank')
GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: A small note, which may be obvious to some: Add additional 

MAX(CASE WHEN f.shortname = 'SHORTNAME' THEN d.data ELSE '' END) AS shortname

for each user profile field you want to retrieve, and add the shortname to the WHERE IN () statement as well.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the flexibility of custom user profile fields, there is not a simpler way of retrieving them using SQL.

If you are using Moodle code, there are built-in functions to retrieve this data for you - profile_load_custom_fields (defined in /user/profile/lib.php) will do this. It is also called from get_complete_user_data. However, both of these functions use multiple DB queries to retrieve the data, so your version will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can get user custom fields with this code:

```
  global $USER;
  $department = $USER->profile['Department'];
  $rank = $USER->profile['PositionRank'];
```

Comment: I need to fetch them in a SQL query.